# How to use PositionedTransition or AlignTranstition to navigate in Navigator.pushNamed?

Tags: flutter

I have a question how to transform in a page transition. The whole content of 1st page should animate to the 2nd page on the x-axis, but not as with SlideTransition() on top of the 1st page. In CSS it would be something like translate.x

Instead I would like to shift/push/move the 1st page content from right to left out of the screen.

[image]

Comment: There's another way to do that. Create a class extending `MaterialPageRoute`, override `buildTransitions` method and use the similar logic as provided by one of the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Output:**

[image]

---

**Code:**

This is `Page1`:

```dart
class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              PageRouteBuilder(
                pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => Page2(),
                transitionsBuilder: (_, anim, __, child) {
                  return Stack(
                    children: [
                      SlideTransition(
                        position: Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset.zero, end: Offset(-1, 0)).animate(anim),
                        child: Page1(),
                      ),
                      SlideTransition(
                        position: Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(1, 0), end: Offset.zero).animate(anim),
                        child: child,
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Text('Go to Page2'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is `Page2`:

```dart
class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(appBar: AppBar());
}
```

Comment: your solution seems to work fine, but when u slow down animations in DevTools Page1() transition is moving faster than child. can you say why? @CopsOnRoad

Comment: @th_lo There are two properties in `PageRouteBuilder`, which you can set depending on your needs; `transitionDuration` and `reverseTransitionDuration`

Comment: I think I've found the problem: I'm trying to open navigate from a drawer, which is not the full device width. I can reduce the gap between the two screens by setting the transition Offset(0.782, 0.0) of the child. thanks